# Display Freezes, Force Close or Wait, and GC_MALLOC and GC_Concurrent are Triggered

Tags: java, android, multithreading, nullpointerexception, numberformatexception

I am trying to use the Thread to process the data in real time to store 8000 strings in a multi-dimensional array. The logic for storing the array has been tested with a string 8000 numbers, that was successful. 
There are two variations for this code the catch (NumberFormatException e) and the catch(NullPointerException e). The logcat for both is listed below. Then it crashes. How do I fix this?

Changing transfer = readMessage; and setting the null to zero did prevent the errors. However, my UI still gets frozen and I get the Force Close or Wait option. Furthermore,
GC_MALLOC and GC_Concurrent are appearing in the error log now.

```
    public double [][]stored = new double[8000][1];
    public static HjorthClass finalValue;
    public String transfer;


    class Task implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            try{
                Thread.sleep(2000);
               }
               catch(InterruptedException e)
                {   
                }

                  for(int a = 0; a<8000; a++)
                {
                        try
                        {
                          double[] convert = new double[1];
                          for(int z=0; z <1;z++)
                              {
                             convert[z]= Double.parseDouble(transfer);
                          }
                          for(int j=0; j<1;j++)
                          {
                             stored[a][j]= convert[j];
                          }
                        }
                        catch(NumberFormatException e)
                        {
                        }

               }


            finalValue = new HjorthClass(stored);
        }}


    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(final Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {

            case MESSAGE_READ:
            byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                String readMessage = new String(readBuf,0,msg.arg1);
                String transfer = readMessage;
                mConversationArrayAdapter.add("Voltage: "+ transfer);
                new Thread(new Task()).start();
                break;
```

logcat with catch(NumberFormatException e)

```
04-07 06:04:01.712: E/AndroidRuntime(24162): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-14
04-07 06:04:01.712: E/AndroidRuntime(24162): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-07 06:04:01.712: E/AndroidRuntime(24162):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseDouble(FloatingPointParser.java:263)
04-07 06:04:01.712: E/AndroidRuntime(24162):    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:318)
04-07 06:04:01.712: E/AndroidRuntime(24162):    at com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChat$Task.run(BluetoothChat.java:248)
04-07 06:04:01.712: E/AndroidRuntime(24162):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

logcat with catch(NullPointerException e)

```
04-07 05:51:55.342: E/AndroidRuntime(23838): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-181
04-07 05:51:55.342: E/AndroidRuntime(23838): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
04-07 05:51:55.342: E/AndroidRuntime(23838):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
04-07 05:51:55.342: E/AndroidRuntime(23838):    at android.app.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:680)
04-07 05:51:55.342: E/AndroidRuntime(23838):    at com.example.android.BluetoothChat.HjorthClass.<init>(HjorthClass.java:18)
04-07 05:51:55.342: E/AndroidRuntime(23838):    at com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChat$Task.run(BluetoothChat.java:263)
04-07 05:51:55.342: E/AndroidRuntime(23838):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Comment: Uh, doing nothing when interrupted? Not the thing to (not) do...

Comment: thanks for telling us. any question?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that it crashes. What should it do when interrupted?

Comment: String transfer = readMessage; replace this with transfer = readMessage;

Comment: @user3495522 also what does this `HjorthClass` do ?. I guess you are updating ui there

Comment: HjorthClass takes the variance of the multi-dimensional array. That's all. My display freezes after the first couple strings.

Comment: it does not give error right? only freeze?

Comment: Only a Freeze that gives me two options, Force Close the application or wait for application to respond.

Comment: Does not logcat message tell you anything? You are probably creating `Handler` in your class `HjorthClass` class, and are doing this from a context of your `Thread`. But in that case you need to prepare a [Looper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html). Your piece of code does not give exact clue on how you're getting your error.

Comment: What happens in your `HjorthClass` constructor?

Comment: Let me upload my HjorthClass. Give me 5 minutes.

Comment: When I comment out the HjorthClass, It still freezes Regardless. The logcat Message is all dalvikvm, dalvikvm heap, GC_FOR_MALLOC, GC_CONCURRENT. There is not a single ERROR on the logcat.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is `transfer` is null,
You can put a condition like this before convert: (the first question which you edit and change your topic)

```
if(transfer ==null)
transfer="0";
```

Comment: Give me 5 minutes! I'll test it!

Comment: Transfer is a string, should I set it to " ";?

Comment: I think you should set it **="0"**,

Comment: Well, the data comes in quickly for the first couple seconds. The display freezes up. It crashes and I get a FATAL EXCEPTION: THREAD 20 and a java.lang.RunTimeException

Comment: I updated the question. There are no more errors, just the dreaded Force Close or Wait option for the application.

Comment: it is a different question actually, I can look today

Comment: Thank you, I updated the title for the new question.

Comment: ok , it will take a long time I think , You can do it with asyntask method in the background ,

Comment: Will it not freeze with asynctask?

Comment: but be sure , it takes long time I think , and a user should not exit app if the process is not ended, you can chech the process is finished or not when a user want to exit from app,

Comment: I think you can look **asynctask** structure in the android ,